# Unable to run Cordova project from cmd

Tags: android, cordova

I am unable to run Cordova project from cmd by executing commands **cordova run android** and **cordova emulate android**. But successfully run form Android studio. Can anyone help to analyse the problem?

when try to run by cmd then the following output will get as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: may be u forgot to build use this  $ cordova build

Comment: same output will get on using cordova build

Comment: then what is problem now

Comment: @khushhal goyal are you able to build browser platform successfully?

Comment: It just show ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME path here, but project is not run on my Android device, also No error message get found

Comment: @kushhal goyal project will not run till you resolve android build issue

Comment: can anyone tell the issue with the build, it doesn't show any error?

Comment: can you share cmd commands that you executed with sequence ??

Answer (score 1):

**Now project run successfully through cmd**

I have just install the java8 & change the java path in environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin`